# How to iterate a loop a certain number of times when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iteration, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

Visual Studio allows debugging line by line, or to jump straight to anywhere using a **breakpoint**.
But for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

**How can I jump immediately to 500th iteration of the loop?**

The fastest I have found so far was to:

- set a **breakpoint** at the begin of the loop, and
- then press `F5` multiple times.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670415/how-to-set-conditional-breakpoints-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a conditional breakpoint that has been already covered few times on StackOverflow.

### Here is answer for your loop-specific problem:

1. Click on the gear button...

[image: Breakpoint setup]

2. Setup your condition

[image: Write down your condition.]

### Another possible solution

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    #if DEBUG
        if( i == 500)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    #endif
}
```